# Updating a key referencing a child table gives constraint error while it shouldn't

Tags: c#, mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

I use MySql and I have 2 related tables.
The 'artikel' child table contains 3 rows each with an'idArtikel' of 1, 2 and 3.
And the 'artikelen' parent table has a row with idArtikel = 2.
If I change the idArtikel in that row to 3 (and Update()), I get an error, stating:

> Update failed..exception Cannot delete or update a parent row: a
>   foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`artikel`, CONSTRAINT
>   `fk_artikel_artikelen` FOREIGN KEY (`idArtikel`) REFERENCES
>   `artikelen` (`idArtikel`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

All the keys are there, but i don't see the problem?!

HERE ARE THE 2 TABLE CREATION SQL scripts:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`artikelen` (
  `idArtikelen` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idKlanten` INT NOT NULL,
  `idOmzetGroepen` INT NOT NULL,
  `idArtikel` INT NOT NULL,
  `Aantal` INT NULL,
  `Omschrijving` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Datum` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `StuksPrijsEx` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
  `BtwPerc` INT NULL,
  `Gefactureerd` TINYINT(1) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idArtikelen`),
  INDEX `idKlanten.idx` (`idKlanten` ASC),
  INDEX `idArtikel.idx` (`idArtikel` ASC),
  INDEX `idOmzetGroepen.idx` (`idOmzetGroepen` ASC),
  INDEX `idArtikelen.idx` (`idArtikelen` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_artikelen_klanten1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idKlanten`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`klanten` (`idKlanten`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`artikel` (
  `idArtikel` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Omschrijving` VARCHAR(35) NULL,
  `Merk` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `Type` VARCHAR(15) NULL,
  `StuksPrijsEx` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
  `idOmzetGroepen` INT NOT NULL,
  `BtwPerc` INT NULL DEFAULT 21,
  INDEX `idOmzetGroepen.idx` (`idOmzetGroepen` ASC),
  INDEX `idArtikel.idx` (`idArtikel` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_artikel_artikelen`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idArtikel`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`artikelen` (`idArtikel`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,

ENGINE = InnoDB
```

#### #

Any help, is appreciated a lot!
Thanks in advance for any input.
Ron.

Comment: You might get an answer quicker if you present a smaller version of your problem. There is too much irrelevant cruft taking away attention.

Comment: I removed some clutter, the rest is relevant i believe..

Comment: It is not about removing clutter. It is about creating the most pure representation of the probem you are having. I think you can express it in terms of ``tableA`` and ``tableB``, both with two columns. Can you provide a "working" example of your probem?

Comment: I shall try to put a working sample together, this could take a few days....

Comment: I also shall investigate a solution to this problem...this is lying in the relation between those 2 tables. The 'artikel' table is also used by another table.If I remove the relation al goes well. (this is logical ;-) .. further investigation on the way...